# Give example of linear map $T:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ for $n \ge 3$ such that $kerT \cap ImT=\{0\}$ and $kerT=\{(x_1..x_n)|x_1+..+x_{n-2}=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Give an example of a linear map $T:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ for $n \ge 3$ such that $kerT \cap ImT=\{0\}$ and $kerT=\{(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)|x_1+x_2+..+x_{n-2}=0\}$. The example should be for a general $n$.

As I understand because $kerT \cap ImT=\{0\}$ then the only vector that belongs to $kerT$ is $(x_1,x_2..x_n)$ such that $x_1=x_2=..=x_n=0$. But I don't understand then what this condition $kerT=\{(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)|x_1+x_2+..+x_{n-2}=0\}$ means if $x_1=..=x_n=0$ anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** Just because $\text{ker }T \cap \text{Im }T = \{0\}$, it doesn't necessarily mean that the kernel will only have the zero vector.

Consider 
$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots ,x_n)=(y,y, \ldots ,y),$$
where $y=x_1+x_2+\dotsb +x_{n-2}$.

It is easy to see that the kernel of this map is the set $\{(x_1,x_2, \ldots , x_n) \, | \, \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}x_i=0.\}$ and the range of this map is the set 
$\{(x_1,x_2, \ldots , x_n) \, | \, x_1=x_2=\dotsb=x_{n}\}$. If there is a vector common to both range and the kernel then, it should be of the form $(a,a,a,\ldots,a)$ such that $(n-2)a=0$. This can happen only when $a=0$. Thus the zero vector is the only common vector.

In fact, one can also have taken the following as another possible example,
$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots ,x_n)=(x_1+x_2+\dotsb +x_{n-2},0, \ldots ,0).$$

Comment: I'm trying to understand why if $kerT \cap ImT=\{0\}$ doesn't necessarily mean that the kernel will only have the zero vector (1). We know that $ImT$ equals the column space of $\mathbb{R^4}$ in our case. So the intuition to explain (1) is that there may be a vector in the spanning set of the kernel which can never be a column in the column space of $\mathbb{R^4}$ right?

Comment: In the second example you gave, could I say that $ImT=Span\{1,\stackrel{n-1 zeroes}{0,...,0}\}$ because only the first element of the vector can change while $kerT=Span\{\stackrel{n-2 zeroes}{0,...,0},1,1\}$ because the sum of the first $n-2$ elements will always result in zero so only the last 2 elements remain?

Comment: @Yos the image is spanned by $(1,0,0, \ldots,0)$ is correct but the kernel is a $n-1$ dimensional subspace because there is only one constraint ($x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_{n-2}=0$) that is determining the kernel. Also if you know rank-nullity theorem, then rank is $1$, hence nullity has to be $n-1$. So kernel will have a basis with $n-1$ vectors.

Comment: So how can I find the spanning set of $kerT$? Or do I prove that $ImT \cap kerT=\{0\}$ because the only way a vector that belongs to a subspace of $dim=n-1$ is equal to a vector in another subspace of $dim=1$ if they're both null vectors?

Comment: @Yos I would recommend you to read about kernels and basis so that you can understand this better and hopefully find the answer as well. Start by asking  yourself: how would you write a general solution of the "homogeneous" equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$?

Comment: I understand now, thanks! The general solution to $x_1+x_2+..+x_{n-2}=0$ would be $(-x_2-x_3-..-x_{n-2}, x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-2})$ so $kerT=Span\{(-1,1,0...0),(-1,0,1,0...0)...(-1,0...0,1))\}$. It is trivial from here to see that $ImT \cap kerT=\{0\}$ right?

Answer (score 1):

An example you may like is $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,....,x_n)=(x_1+x_2+....+x_{n-2},0,0,.....,0)$ the matrix representation of which is $T=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&....1&0&0\\0&0&....0&0&0\\.&.&.&.\\0&0&....0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

You can see $T$ does not have full rank and ker($T$)$=${$(x_1,...,x_n):x_1+x_2+....+x_{n-2}=0$}.(***which turns out to be the same as posted in the first answer***).

---

A more simplest is the zero transformation i.e. $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,....,x_n)=(0,0,0,......,0)$ for which ker($T$)$=\mathbb R^n$ and Range($T$)$=O$ so that $ker(T)\cap Range(T)=\emptyset$ is trivially satisfied.

Comment: The first example you gave is already given in my answer (see at the end). Your second example, the zero transformation does not satisfy OP's requirement of  kernel being the set given in the problem.

Comment: @Anurag A....A zero transformation is a particular example of the OP's requirement as he needed just an example (*particular case of general result* which you have already stated in your answer.)

Comment: but for the zero transformation, the kernel is $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not just $\{(x_1,x_2, \ldots , x_n) \, | \, x_1+x_2+\dotsb +x_{n-2}=0\}$, which is one of OP's requirements.

Comment: Doesn't the zero transformation satisfy this condition? And I know that it is not the only one. The asker is looking for an example and it is the simplest one!

Comment: I think you are missing the point: Kernel should be "equal" to that set. For the zero transformation, kernel contains OP's set as a proper subset, hence not equal. So the zero transformation is NOT a correct answer to OP's question.

Comment: oh! yes...I missed it.